# mysql small count issue on same table

Tags: mysql

Please find db structure as following...

```
| id | account_number  | referred_by  |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  1 | ac203003        | ac203005     |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  2 | ac203004        | ac203005     |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
|  3 | ac203005        | ac203004     |
+----+-----------------+--------------+
```

I want to achieve following results...

```
id, account_number, total_referred 
1,  ac203005, 2
2, ac203003m 0
3, ac203004, 1
```

And i am using following query...

```
SELECT id, account_number, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `member_tbl` WHERE referred_by = account_number) AS total_referred
FROM `member_tbl`
GROUP BY id, account_number
```

but its not giving expected results, please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use table aliases to do this correctly:

```
SELECT id, account_number, 
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `member_tbl` t2
        WHERE t2.referred_by = t1.account_number
       ) AS total_referred
FROM `member_tbl` t1;
```

Your original query had `referred_by = account_number`.  Without aliases, these would come from the same row -- and the value would be `0`.

Also, I removed the outer `group by`.  It doesn't seem necessary, unless you want to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to join the table on itself. This way you can avoid the subquery. There might be performance gains with this approach.

```
select b.id, b.account_number, count(a.referred_by) 
from member_tbl a inner join member_tbl b 
on a.referred_by=b.account_number 
group by (a.referred_by);
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1393/2

Another test, with more data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d216/1

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you take project, as i need some more improvements to this query, if you could help, it would be a small work

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.account_number, count(t2.referred_by)
from (select account_number from member_tbl) t1
left join member_tbl t2 on
t1.account_number = t2.referred_by
group by t1.account_number;
```

**[Fiddle for your data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1393/10)**

**[Fiddle with more data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d216/2)**